# Css Triangle not rendering properly in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am trying to create a css trianlge for the header navigation.I have achieved it but it is not rendering properly in IE.

Here is the Working Fiddle solution for the sample i have created.I have fixed the position but when i try to run in IE(Currently i have IE 11.0) the triangle is rendered as a square box but when i try to run it in Chrome and FF it is working fine.

Fiddler : http://jsfiddle.net/cKnyQ/20/

```
a:hover:after {
            background: white;
            border: solid black;
            border-width: 1px 1px 0 0;
            bottom: 0px;
            content: ' ';
            display: block;
            height: 10px;
            left: 32px;
            position: absolute;
            width: 10px;
            z-index: 99;
            -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
            -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
        }
```

Comment: Have a look at this: http://mrcoles.com/blog/callout-box-css-border-triangles-cross-browser/

Comment: I don't know that IE supports -webkit-transform styles. (Try just 'transform')

Comment: `-webkit` is just for Webkit (Chrome/Safari/Opera15+). You've missed the other vendors' prefixes such as `-ms`, and the W3C standard property.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cKnyQ/23/ works in IE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `-ms-transform: rotate(-45deg)`

Comment: Also indicate other browsers prefixes!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Akshay mohite. As a side note i have edited the js fiddle with the searched solution.

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/cKnyQ/25/

```
#Container a:hover::after {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        border: 8px solid black;
        border-bottom-color: white;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0px;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -12px;
        background: white;
    }
```